# An unhandled exception occurred in System.Configuration.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, dataset

This the first time for me working in data set. I am using c# application linked with access data base and data set model.

in the solution explorers I click add > new Item >data> dataset then I drag and drop the data base from server explorer to the data set.
 then  I put the controls in the form and for the text boxs I go to the property >databinding > text> 'databaserecords' is there any problem? why when I run the program an error message says?

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll
```

the app.config page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>
  </runtime>
    <configSections>


    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Hptal.Properties.Settings.EmplyeesConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\aq99s\Documents\Emplyees.accdb"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

the setting designer:

```
namespace Hptal.Properties {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "14.0.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.ConnectionString)]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\aq99s\\Documents\\Emplyees.a" +
            "ccdb")]
        public string EmplyeesConnectionString {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["EmplyeesConnectionString"]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose the connection can any one help?

Comment: Try this :-  connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\aq99s\Documents\Emplyees.accdb;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

Comment: What's the message in the exception?

Comment: @lan message is  An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll